# Android - how can I generate SHA-1 fingerprint

Tags: android, eclipse, sha1

I get many tutorial for generate SHA-1 fingerprint (in general not just for maps) , but I want know whats the best way & what difference between this ways .

First way  (keytool)

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Or by mention userprofile

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Second way (From Eclipse )

Window > Preferences > Android > Build
[image]

Thank you in advance & sorry for disturb

Comment: I'm pretty sure eclipse uses the same command line.

Comment: Both give me the same result , but now one mention this way why ? it easier than write command

Comment: Well, using a GUI is less tedious than using the command line I guess... At least for some people.

Answer (score 1):

### Try like this

first you can download and instal openssl and jdk file.

1. open command prompt and copy and paste jdk file path like this

   ```
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin>
   ```
2. Next Go to C:>User folder>Select (User name) folder> .android folder is there open that folder and copy the link 
   (or)
   type the text line like this

   keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users(user name).android\debug.keystore"

   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users(user name).android\debug.keystore"

   Enter keystore password: android

and click enter 
list out the sha1 and md5 keys.